# Javascript Block Form Submission

Tags: javascript, html

How would I block form submission if the user presses cancel for confirmation of selecting Doctor.

```
        <form method="post" action="registration.php" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select name="role" id="role">
            <option value="Patient">Patient</option>
            <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
            <option value="Nurse" >Nurse</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#role").change(function(){
         var val = $(this).val();

          switch (val){
            case "Doctor":
              var d = confirm("Are you a doctor?");
          }
        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the submission of the form you can use `return false` on the `onsubmit` attribute of the form.

Since you already have a call to the `validateMyForm()` function there, you just need to make sure that this function return false:

```
function validateMyForm() {
    ....
    // do some checks...
    return false;
}
```

If you to prevent the submission of the form based on the answer to your `confirm`, you should save the answer in some variable that you can use later on:

```
<script>
    var d;
    $("#role").change(function(){
     var val = $(this).val();

      switch (val){
        case "Doctor":
          d = confirm("Are you a doctor?");
      }
    }); 
</script>
```

And inside the function:

```
function validateMyForm() {
    if (!d) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `d` variable will be `false` if cancel is pressed, so:

```js
$("#role").change(function(){
  let val = $(this).val();
  let blockSubmit = false;
  
  if (val == 'Doctor') {
      let d = confirm("Are you a doctor?");
      blockSubmit = !d;
  }
  else {
    blockSubmit = false
  }
   
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', blockSubmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="registration.php" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return validateMyForm();">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select name="role" id="role">
    <option value="Patient">Patient</option>
    <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
    <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If you are doing this, do not forget to activate the input in case the #role switch again.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).disable is not a function(…)

Comment: @Susan apologies, my memory escaped me.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Please use the snippet editor instead of external pages unless the snippet editor does not allow what you are doing

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan, still getting used it to :-)

Comment: Also no need for a switch here at all `$("#role").change(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', !confirm("Are you a doctor?"));
});`

Comment: @mplungjan agree, but I don't want the code to deviate too much from author's original